# Add prefix to devise error helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have devise configured correctly with my application and the helper is working to display individual error messages next to the fields. Currently the errors appear as "can't be blank" or "has already been taken". I want to add a prefix to it, like "Username can't be blank" or "Email
has already been taken" but can't figure out how.

This is basically what I want to achieve but doesn't work

```
<%= "Username" + errors_for @user, :username %>
```

user.rb

```
   def errors_for(model, attribute)
      if model.errors[attribute].present?
        content_tag :div, :class => 'error_explanation' do
          model.errors[attribute].join(", ")
        end
      end
    end
```

devise/registrations/new.html.erb

```
<%= f.text_field :first_name, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'First name' %>
  <%= errors_for @user, :first_name %>
  <br>
  <%= f.text_field :username, autofocus: true, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Username'%>
  <%= errors_for @user, :username %>
  <br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get full message by:

```
@user.errors.full_messages_for(:first_name)
@user.errors.full_messages_for(:username)
```

Or use

```
@user.errors.full_messages
```

to get all full error messages.

You can change model field name and error message in language file: `config/locales/**.yml`( in `devise` scope.)

*Example: If your app language is English, edit your `config/locales/en.yml`*

```
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        first_name: "your custom field name"
    errors:
      messages:
        blank: "your custom error message"
```

You can get more information from [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works but I'm getting ["First name can't be blank"] and want to remove the [" "] and style the error message. How do I do that?